# Make image of the OS

Tags: debian, images, operating-systems

I am using a Nano Pi device which has Debian OS in it. The OS image is existing in its internal memory (8 GB). The total size of the used memory is somewhat 4GB. I want to take a backup of this OS into an image file.

After doing

```
dd if=/dev/mmcblk1 of=NanoPi.img bs=8M status=progress
```

The total image file size goes up to 8GB. How can I make the image of only the used by memory and not all?

Comment: You could also try and resize your partition first, and then make the image with `dd`

Comment: but .. image will be made of the entire block right ... mmcblk1 ... which will have a boot partition mmcblk1p0, the main partition mmcblk1p1 and the new partition mmcblk1p2 ...so .. how will resizing the partition help?

Comment: ah, I misread your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this easily using `dd` because block device is just a dump of bytes. It may contain data of long deleted files in unallocated space. `dd` is not aware of that because it is filesystem's job. You have few options:

### Keep using dd

... and accept larger space useage. Instead do something like `dd if=/dev/mmcblk1 of=NanoPi.img bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress`. Smaller block size gives you a little bit more security in case of read errors. If `dd` fails to read at least one sector - rest of the block will be not processed. Block size is the max amount of bytes you may loose for one bad sector. `conv=noerror` ensures cloning continues in case of error. `conv=sync` shifts pointer in destination file forward in case of read errors so data remains aligned and thus valid.

You can pipe `dd` output through `gzip` to compress data and save some space:
`dd if=/dev/mmcblk1 bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress | gzip -c > NanoPi.img.gz`
To get back raw image do `gunzip -c ./NanoPi.img.gz > NanoPi.img`.

### Use rsync

... and deal with raw files. `rsync -aAXv /path/to/mounted/mmcblk1 /path/to/destination/folder`. This may or may not work for you depending if your filesystem is mounted or not.